# How do parameters work in C - run a function with a string as a param

Tags: c

I am very new to C, so please forgive my ignorance.

I am trying to run this program:

```
int main()
{
    const char *str = "EWEWEWEEW";

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)
    {
        char ch = str[i];
        
        if (strlen(str) != 10) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
        
    return 1;
}
```

I wanted it so, just like in JS, you can run the program with the string included as a param:

Main would be like this `int main(str)` and then I would run the program like this:

`main("EWEWEWEEW")` so it returns either 0 or 1.

How can I achieve this in C?

Thanks

Comment: `main()` takes 2 (actually 3) arguments `int main (int argc, char **argv)` where `argc` is your argument count and `argv` is your argument vector (an array of pointers to strings with the next pointer after the last string set `NULL` as a sentinel). `argv[0]` is always the name of the program being run. . So if you run `./yourprogram "EWEWEWEEW"` then `argc == 2` and `argv` contains as `argv[0]` `/path/to/yourprogram` and `argv[1]` is `"EWEWEWEEW"`  and `argv[2] == NULL`

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your code can be replaced with `return strlen(str) == 10`.

Comment: `main` is called by the runtime system when you run the executable. If you want to call a function within your code, why not create a new function that takes the relevant parameter?

Comment: Additionally, checking `if (strlen(str) != 10)` inside a loop declared `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)` doesn't really make much sense. `str` never changes, so for any given `str` the condition `if (strlen(str) != 10)` is already fixed before you enter the loop. No need to check it every iteration.

Comment: sorry @DavidC.Rankin understand what you are saying, should have explained myself better. This is just an example so I can get some help on how to evaluate a string as an argument. My original code is bigger and contains other conditions, not just if the string is different than 10.

Comment: as I am very new to C, would be nice to have some code to illustrate your answers. @Chase I like your idea, is it possible for you to write up a function to verify my string so I can see how that would work?

Comment: @RandomDeveloper To me it's unclear what you are asking. Do you want `main` to take a text string as input or do you want some other function that takes a text string as input? That makes a difference because `main` is a special function in C

Comment: Further it's unclear what you want to do. What is your criteria for returning 0 and What is your criteria for returning 1 ? Your current code looks at string length... is that it?

Comment: if you say (bearing in mind that I am new) that main is a special function it makes more sense to then have a new function that evaluates the string

Comment: sorry @4386427 its not about the criteria, I just need to understand how to pass a string as a param, it can be in the current function, or a new function

Comment: @RandomDeveloper It depends on what you want to do...

Comment: Let me know what compiler are you using and I'll add an example compile string showing how to enable *Full Compiler Warnings*.

Comment: I am using Vs code

Comment: @4386427 I just want to return 0 if the string evaluates to different than 10 characters and 1 if not.

Comment: VScode is an editor. Are you using the VS compiler (`cl.exe`) or `gcc`?

Comment: code runner extension in vs code

Comment: The example on [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) shows it is using `gcc` to compile C. I'll add an example. I STRENUOUSLY recommend you compile from the command line and not risk warnings or errors being masked by some extension. You will have to configure the code runner config  file to include the necessary options.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking. You want a program that will return `0` or `1` depending on whether the target string `"EWEWEWEEW"` is the argument passed to `main()`. Continuing from my comment above related to `main()`.

What I understand from the last comment is you just want to test whether a string provided as an argument is the target string. You can do that trivially with `strcmp()` for the string comparison. You can write your code to return `0` if the argument is provided but not `"EWEWEWEEW"`, return `1` if the argument is `"EWEWEWEEW"` or return some other value (say `2`) if no argument was provided, e.g.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TARGET "EWEWEWEEW"

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  
  if (argc > 1) {
    return strcmp (argv[1], TARGET) == 0;
  }
  
  return 2;
}
```

`strcmp()` returns `-1` if `argv[1]` sorts before `TARGET`, `0` if the strings are equal and `1` if `TARGET` sorts before `argv[1]`. By returning the result of the equality `strcmp (argv[1], TARGET) == 0` you force a return of `1` (true) if the strings match or `0` if they don't and you don't have to worry about the positive/negative aspect of the `strcmp()` return.

If you attempt the comparison with `strlen()` all that tells you is the length of the string. If that is what you want, then use that instead. Understand though, using `strlen()` that `"EWEWEWEEW"` and `"WEEWEWEWE"` will return the same thing.

**Compile With Full Warnings Enabled -- Every Time**

Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it.

Adding the `c11` standard to the compile string, and output the executable named `checkstring` I used:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -Ofast -o bin/checkstring checkstring.c
```

For a DEBUG build, change `-Ofast` to `-g` to generate a symbol table for the `gdb` debugger to read.

(I have a `bin` subdirectory in my source code directory so I can compile and output an executable in a separate directory - makes clean up easier)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/checkstring EWEWEWEEW
$ echo $?
1
```

(**note:** quotes around your string argument are only needed if your string contains whitespace to prevent word-splitting by the shell)

or

```
$ ./bin/checkstring bananas
$ echo $?
0
```

and finally

```
$ ./bin/checkstring
$ echo $?
2
```

Let me know if that is what you are after, if not I'm happy to help further.

Answer (score 0):

> ... I just need to understand how to pass a string as a param

Well, simply take a look at how it's done by the standard string functions.

Example: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html says:

> size_t strlen(const char *s);

It kind of tells it all. To pass a string, you pass a char pointer, i.e. `char*`. In other words, in C you don't actually pass the text string as a value. Instead you pass a pointer to the text string.

The `const` is saying that the string will/can not be changed by the function. If the function is going to modify the string, just remove the `const`

So you can do:

```
int foo(const char *s)
{
    if (strlen(s) == 10) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

and call it like

```
int a = foo("abcdef");
int b = foo("1234567890");

const char* str = "Hello world";
int c = foo(str);

char x[] = "More text";
int d = foo(x);
```

Notice how `foo("abcdef");` looks as-if you pass a text string. But that's not what happens. The compiler will place the "abcdef" somewhere in memory and then pass a pointer to that memory to the function.

Final note:

Notice that the length of a string is not the same as the number of characters used for storing the string. This is because C strings require an extra character (a '\0' character) for indicating "end-of-string". So

```
"abc" has length 3 but is stored using 4 characters, i.e. 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'
```

so

```
strlen("abc") gives 3
sizeof("abc") gives 4
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this, why do I have to store the result function in a variable to call it? Can it simply not just be `foo("aaasas")`

Comment: @RandomDeveloper Yes, you can. C allows you to ignore return values. But... what would be the purpose of calling this specific function and then ignoring the return value? If you don't use the return value, there is no reason to call the function. For other functions it could make sense but not here...

Comment: Also understand `"aaasas"` is a *String-Literal* created in Read-Only memory (except on one non-standard compiler) and if your function attempts to modify the string literal, you will likely SegFault. It is perfectly fine where there is no modification, but some string functions (like `strtok()`) modify the original. Just be aware of the difference.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin True, in the above code, the only string that we can modify is `x`. But then again... this code doesn't modify the strings.

Comment: @4386427 - I know you know, but in the question, my answer and yours the literals have been thrown around with no further comment (because there was no modification), but just to make sure the Questioner knows that `char *foo = "stuff";` can't be modified while `char foo[] = "stuff";` can (ignoring the *compound literal* initializer and VS for now)